# Backbone.Marionette 1.2 has no method 'bindTo'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

```
userView = Marionette.View.extend
  tagName: "h1"
  initialize:->
    @bindTo @model, "change:name", @render, this
  render: ->
    @$el.html  @model.get('name')
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bindTo'
```

I used backbone 1.1.0 So what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, "change:name", this.rednder)
```

if you want to use the function bindTo, you have to use it on instance of Backbone.EventBinder object. Example [here](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.eventbinder#bind-events)